# Iterator for a list of sorted lists using a priority queue

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue

I found the following interview question [here.](https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/SortedIterator-consists-of-List-of-Lists-with-sorted-int-values-in-each-list-You-have-to-give-next-sorted-value-when-cal-QTN_2553035.htm)

> SortedIterator - consists of List of Lists with sorted int values in
>   each list. You have to give next sorted value when call next().
>
> have to implement methods
>   * constructor
>   * next()
>   * hasNext()
>
> [ [1, 4, 5, 8, 9], [3, 4, 4, 6], [0, 2, 8] ]
>
> next() -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4...

I wrote a quick implementation in Java:

```
package com.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortedIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

    private final List<Integer> mFlattenedList;
    private final Iterator<Integer> mIntegerIterator;

    SortedIterator(final List<List<Integer>> lists) {
        mFlattenedList = flattenLists(lists);
        mIntegerIterator = mFlattenedList.iterator();
    }

    private List<Integer> flattenLists(final List<List<Integer>> lists) {
        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Integer> list : lists) {
            for (int value : list) {
                result.add(value);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return mIntegerIterator.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        return mIntegerIterator.next();
    }
}
```

Time: O (K * N) to flatten the input list of lists + O (N*K) to iterate over the flattened list = O (N * K)

Space: O (N * K) to store the flattened list.

N - number of lists.

K - number of elements in each list.

But the [answer](https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/SortedIterator-consists-of-List-of-Lists-with-sorted-int-values-in-each-list-You-have-to-give-next-sorted-value-when-cal-QTN_2553035.htm) from the link says:

> There is a solution with time complexity O(logN) using a priority
>   queue. Maybe an interviewer expected something like that, I don't
>   know.

How is `O (log N)` possible? If a priority queue is used, every time we call `hasNext()`, we'll need to check if the queue is empty (`O(1)`). Then we call `next()` which extracts the min element from the queue (`O(log (N*K)`) for any implementation) according to the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Summary_of_running_times). Since we need to call `next()` N * K times, it takes us `O(N * K * log (N*K)` to iterate over all the elements.

Comment: `nestedList.stream().flatMap(identity()).sorted().iterator()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That's basically what OP is doing and doesn't get O(log N) complexity per element...

Comment: `O(n lg n)` is surely `O(lg n)` per element for `n` elements assuming the entire data is consumed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm sure you don't want your application to hang for a few seconds upon construction of a huge `SortedIterator`. There's always a tradeoff between precomputation complexity and per-element complexity.

Comment: Under the assumption that this action is carried out at startup rather that once per action, and that this latency is somehow detectable then yes. If it's a microservice running this once per request, for example, it makes no difference. Fundamentally you are right, @pkpnd, it's a throughput vs latency question - but I dislike these "cute" algorithmic problems as they are usually not relevant in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution's O(logN) complexity is the complexity *per element*, not the complexity to iterate over all values.

The solution looks something like this:

- First define a new class called `ListValue` that stores a value as well as the index of the list it came from. These should be comparable to other `ListValue` objects using the value.
- Constructor: Initialize a `PriorityQueue<ListValue>` called `pq` and place the first element from each of the N lists into `pq`.
- next(): Pop the `ListValue` at the front of `pq`. The value inside is the value to be returned, but first, move the next element from that `ListValue`'s list into `pq`. Complexity is O(log N), since we remove one element and add one element to `pq`, which contains at most N elements.

Note that the solution doesn't keep all N*K values in the priority queue at once, only the single "next" value from each of the N lists. Hence, the priority queue has (at most) N elements at all times, so its operations are all O(log N).

To understand why this works, recall that each list is already sorted, so the minimum unused value must appear at the "front" of some list (not including the values already consumed). Then, note that the priority queue contains precisely the "front" element of each list -- we force this to happen in `next()` when we add an element to `pq` from the same list as the element we removed. Therefore, at all times `pq` will contain the minimum unused value (until all values are exhausted).